# Trying to run Civi cron Jobs using Drupal cron?

Tags: drupal, cron-job, pantheon

I'm running Civicrm 4.4.7 on Pantheon.

I added the module called 'Elysa Cron' to my Drupal site which allows the option of running Civi cron whenever Drupal cron is run. The status report in Drupal shows that Civicron is running but nothing happens in Civicrm.
Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: My first fought is that all scheduled jobs are disabled. Could you check this? You can see all scheduled jobs in CiviCRM at administer --> system settings -> scheduled jobs

Comment: The Jobs are enabled and do run if I execute them manually or by running drush from a remote url or through command line. I need it to run using drupal cron though.

Comment: Did you check out the wiki page about running cron, http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-Command-lineSyntaxforRunningJobs? And also there is a drupal module for running the civicrm cron from within the drupal cron: https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_cron

Comment: We do have civicrm_cron module enabled but still doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Just to summarize all the places to look. If you've chosen to try to run CiviCRM cron from Drupal, you need the [civicrm_cron module](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_cron). Then in the Elysia Cron settings: admin/config/system/cron/settings take a look at the settings for the civicrm_cron job and make sure it's enabled. It's probably called: civicrm_cron_cron. Though if you're seeing civicrm_cron in watchdog then it's being called.

The next step is to check that you can manually run cron by executing the cronjob by entering the url for the cronjob in the url (with the site key set in civicrm.settings.php), by using a drush command, or by clicking the Execute Now button next to the scheduled job in Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs. Make sure those scheduled jobs are enabled and have a frequent enough schedule. (More info here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-Command-lineSyntaxforRunningJobs).

If the scheduled jobs are working but still not being called from Drupal, then you may want to see if you're able to get them to run via third-party cron service such as EasyCron and create a cronjob such as 
`*/15 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://mysite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username&pass=password&key=site-key'`.

I'm also running CiviCRM 4.4.14 on Pantheon and I'm using an external cronjob to call Elysia Cron and it's triggering CiviCRM cron. So I know that in general it should work.

Comment: I am able to execute the jobs through the civicrm ui and with drush but not by the drupal civicrm_cron. Thanks for your response. @herb, did you start out with the civicrm starter_kit distribution or did you install civicrm on a regular site?

Comment: I used the civicrm_starterkit but I've moved away from it. I think it worked in both instances.